# How can I get a response without a backslash and double quotes?(Android, Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, sharedpreferences

Implementing profile modification. The function has the ability to request values for image change and nickname change to the server, and the server hands over the modified nickname value and the value of the base64 decoded image to the response value. There is a problem implementing the feature, where the value of the image is answered correctly, but the value of the modified nickname is not a pure string value, but contains odd double quotation and backslash values. What is wrong with that?

**This is all code i coded**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**This is result from Log:**

```
resultCode : CNAPResponse(nickname="abcdefg", image=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
```

**This is also result but from Postman:**

[image]

In the sharedPreference file, values seem to be stored properly in the form of a string, but when the response values are checked with log and postman, the nickname values among the response values differ from each other, especially postman, and the nickname values include double quotes and backslashes.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You'll be more successful getting help if you follow the advice in these links. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is no problem uploading the image to the server. I sent the revised nickname value to the server and received the response value, but I got a strange value, so I asked a question.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the link. It is not about what you're asking about. It's about how you are posting images of code here on this website. I don't answer questions with pictures of code because it's hard to read and I would have to retype a bunch of it to give a proper answer. But also your question has way too much code posted. You should narrow it down to only the relevant parts.

Comment: This is how to put your source code into [stackoverflow](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c). The third method is common. Can you share your code instead of image code. It can't search by reviewer and It is high potential to Close your question.

Comment: If you're talking about the `nickname` field in your Postman output (if you're going to post huge images like that at least highlight the part you want us to look at!) then it contains escaped quotes. `\"` in a string allows you to add the `"` character as part of the string itself, so it won't be interpreted as the start or end delimiter. Why it's there I don't know, but the nickname in your log output is just `abcdefg`, but in the Postman output it's `박종준`, so you're not comparing the same thing. Maybe there are quotes in the Korean version, or maybe it adds quotes around Hangul?

Comment: I captured the wrong result and uploaded it. I captured the wrong result and uploaded it. However, when I modified my nickname in English and requested it to the server, the \" is still attached...

Comment: @cactustictacs is there no ways to solve this problem?

Comment: @박종준 so you're saying when you get a response back from the server, it has quotes around the username? (And escaping them so they're part of the string itself, i.e. the nickname is `"abcd"` not `abcd`) If so that sounds like a server issue, and the server's either storing the name without quotes but adds them to the response, or it's adding quotes when it stores the name, or you're adding the quotes yourself when you send the data to the server. If you want to fix it you need to check what's happening at each of these steps. Or you could just strip out the `\"` at each end if it's always there